# Groovy appending "." when interpolating a variable

Tags: groovy, interpolation, string-interpolation

I am creating an MSSQL SQL statement in groovy function and with the schema as one of the parameter.

```
static createSQL(String schema){
    
   def sql = "INSERT INTO ${schema}.table1 VALUES(?)";
}
```

When running this function I get the error

```
java.lang.Exception groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: table1 for class: java.lang.String
```

I have tried the following alternatives but nothing works.

```
[${schema}].table1
${schema}.[table1]
${schema}\\.table1
```

How can I avoid table1 being read as property of the variable `schema`?

Comment: Groovy wouldn't do that. Either this is an SQL exception, or your actual code is different from what you're showing here. Please add the stack trace.

Comment: I added the complete exception log. We are actually using an IDE of a proprietary software which uses groovy script. I believe we are using pure groovy but I don't know for sure. The code I write is our actual code and I just changed the values

Comment: I'd like to second, that this is not how groovy would work and you can easily confirm this in a groovysh. So there is some puzzle piece missing. Most likely the environment you are running this manipulates those queries beforehand or your example is oversimplified. This _is_ the behaviour you would get for `"... $schema.table ..."`. Have you tried just `+` concating the string (like in Java)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell GroovySQL that it's not a value (which requires quoting)

```
def sql = "INSERT INTO ${Sql.expand(schema)}.table1 VALUES(?)";
```